# How to pass mouse events from top sprite to bottom sprite?

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, mousemove

I am loading an external SWF onto my stage, using the 'Loader' class.
I then put the 'Loader' class in a 'MovieClip' object, and add it to the stage.
I now add another layer on top of that which is transparent, and has an 'x' button in the top right corner and a border around it.
(client requirements dictate that these two layers are separate, meaning - I can't add the 'x' and border to the externally loaded SWF itself).

Here is what both layers look like separatly:

[image]

and here is what both layers look on top of each other:
[image]

What I need is this :
I have an event catcher for the 'mouse roll-over' and 'mouse roll-out' and 'mouse click' of the top layer.
When 'roll-over' happens - I change the width of the border.
When the 'x' is clicked - I hide both layers.

The problem is - the bottom layer of the externally loaded SWF is an interactive SWF with animation.
I need to be able for the mouse to interact with the bottom layer, too.

I tried dispatching the 'Mouse-Move' event to the 'MovieClip' that holds the SWF and tried dispatching it to the 'Loader' object inside of it,
but it didn't work.

(I should be able to see some animation changing when the mouse is over it).

How can I achieve what I need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to split up your border and "x" icon into two separate objects. Set the `mouseEnabled` property on the border object to `false`, and let it completely cover the SWF you loaded.  Now the "x" icon only needs to be as big as the icon itself, and it will only cover a small portion of the loaded SWF.

Now the only thing that should "steal" the mouse events would be the "x" icon, which I imagine would be acceptable to your client :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to the top layer is blocking the mouse tracking for the bottom layer, Checks the clear area of the top layer, there should not be any transparent object like a rectangle with alpha in 0.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what I need to do.
There is a reason why I need to have a layer on top of the externally loaded SWF (client request), and in order for it not to block the view of the banner - I set it's alpha to '0' (I need this layer for 2 reasons - for adding a border and 'x' button on it, and for detecting hovering over - I can't do this in the externally loaded SWF because it has masks to it).